# Angular Cli: after eject i can't use ng commands parameters, any alternatives for ng params?

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

Angular Cli: after eject i can't use ng commands like `ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false`

1. is there is a webpack alternative options for:

   - choosing app to build inside .angular-cli.json
   - output hashing ture.false
2. i am thinking of using gulp alongside with angular cli without ejecting the webpack and avoid ejecting webpack out of angular , what do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked these issues,

- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5229
- https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5433

a workaround is being suggested ng eject --prod; possibly you can try that.

Answer (score 0):

for anyone having same problem, i found in this cli documentation https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject

you can pass parameters to `ng eject` that you pass for `ng build` with full documentation in this page

`ng eject` ejects your app and output the proper webpack configuration and scripts.

This command uses the same flags as `ng build`, generating webpack configuration to match those flags.

You can use `--force` to overwrite existing configurations. You can eject multiple times, to have a dev and prod config for instance, by renaming the ejected configuration and using the `--force` flag.